# Rails FasterCSV "unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, fastercsv

I'm having an issue with FasterCSV and my rake db:seeds migration. I get the error: 
"rake aborted! Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n (line 2)" 
on the following seeds.rb data:

```
require 'csv' 

directory = "db/init_data/"

file_name = "gardenzing020812.csv"
path_to_file = directory + file_name
puts 'Loading Plant records'
# Pre-load all Plant records
n=0
CSV.foreach(path_to_file) do |row|
  Plant.create! :name => row[1],
  :plant_type => row[3],
  :group => row[2],
  :image_path => row[45],
  :height => row[5],
  :sow_inside_outside => row[8]
n=n+1
end
```

I've searched for a solution to this problem and have discovered that for a lot of folks it's a UTF-8 encoding problem. I've tried requiring iconv and :encoding => 'u', but that then gives me the error "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8".

I'm a newbie, and I can't figure out if it's really an encoding issue that I need to crack (which I've been trying to do unsuccessfully and if so, I could really use some guidance) or, more likely I feel, that I've made a simple misstep and done something wrong with the way I've set up seeds.rb and possibly my excel -> csv file. There's no bad or awkward data in the csv file. It's simple one-word strings, text and integers. Please help!

Comment: Can you show us which part of the CSV is causing trouble?

Comment: @muistooshort let me know if you need a more zoomed-in shot. This is the file in its entirety. I truncated my seeds.rb file in the post, but my actual code parses all the columns in this sheet.

Comment: Any chance of seeing the raw CSV?

Comment: I see now in the text file that some of my columns have picked up quotes. Is that the issue?

Comment: That sounds like it could be the problem. You'd be better off quoting all the column values just to be safe.

Comment: I've sliced out all the columns that were creating "" around the text, and the migration is still giving me the same error. I'll try putting quotes around everything next, but I was really hoping to avoid that solution as it kinda compromises the original excel doc.

Comment: Why does the title say "fastercsv", when you require "csv"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was as simple as clearing all the formatting off in the csv. Excel seems to have a habit of retaining a lot of the formatting after saving in a csv file, which was causing the failure. After I copied and pasted all the data with no formatting in a new csv file, it was fine.

Answer (score 5):

Use `String.encode(universal_newline: true)` instead gsub.
It converting CRLF and CR to LF # Always break lines with \n

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, but I wanted to say that I have been looking this error across the web day and night for a long time and finally found the solution in the comments, by [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short).

I finally got it to work when I put quotes around all of my values.

EDIT: *Link to answer!!!* [Rails FasterCSV "unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200175/rails-fastercsv-unquoted-fields-do-not-allow-r-or-n/27536887?noredirect=1#comment11589600_9200175)

Comment: Can you at least link the post you found it in so people don't have to dig though 5000 of his answers?

Comment: @Marv I suspect they're talking about my "You'd be better off quoting all the column values just to be safe." comment on this question. And I'm a little shy of 5000 answers :)

Comment: @muistooshort Oh. Err, this happened while going through the First Answers review queue. I thought he found the solution in one of your other answers. My bad!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200175/rails-fastercsv-unquoted-fields-do-not-allow-r-or-n/27536887?noredirect=1#comment11589600_9200175

Comment: Is there any chance someone could post a code example as to what it looks like to put quotes around the values?  is it `:plant_type => row["3"],` ? (assume not)